# How to execute some code only after code from a different file has finished?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, es6-promise

I'm using AngularJS and I have a controller where I handle the authentication of the user. Then I have several different controllers that make API calls. Those API calls need to be executed AFTER the authentication code has finished.

The problem is that since I load my controllers in parallel like the following, I don't even know which file will load and execute first:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app/controllers/authController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app/controllers/softwareController.js"></script>
```

I think this means that the flag or promise (to know when authentication has finished) needs to be declared BEFORE including those files, as a global flag.

But I can't declare the promise outside&before the files because I wouldn't be able to pass the resolve function to it (because the authentication function wouldn't even be declared yet).

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: What abaout a callback or an event emit - listener?

Comment: I think the best option is that the authentication controller emits an event when it ends and the other controllers listen to it and also check if it's done on init (if is possible that these controllers are loaded after authentication have finished). So you can put the logic in a function that is called on init if user is authenticated and on the event listener

Answer (score 0):

Make a service for authentication and inject it into your controllers. In your service, add a function for authentication with a success callback. Inject this service into your controllers. In your controllers you can execute your login inside the success callback function.

Service

```
angular.module('app', []).service('authService', function(){
   this.authenticate = function(successCallback) {
      // Perform authentication here
      successCallback();
   }
});
```

Controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, authService){
   authService.authenticate(function onSuccess(){
      // Authentication was successful
   });
});
```

Comment: The AngularJS framework and its $http service is promise-based. It would be wiser to have the `authService` return promises.

Comment: Yes promise based solution is better and gives more control. However, the question didn't specifically say that http request is made. Maybe the user only intends to validate info stored in a cookie.